# What is EntityReference

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

If I want to bind two Entity Framework objects `person1`, `person2` with parent-son relation. Say, objects are from different `ObjectContexts` or one is detached. Well and now, I would like to write something like:

`person1.Parent = person2;`

This fails on `SaveChanges()`. So I write:

`person1.ParentReference.EntityKey = person2.EntityKey;`

Is this a right solution for that problem or should one always reload the "bad" object (object which is currently in another `ObjectContext`)?

Comment: I don't think you should set the reference directly, it probably bypasses some tracking stuff. Please provide details of how it fails on `SaveChanges`?

Answer (score 0):

To give you a direct answer

Image your table

```
[Tbl_Persons]

PersonId   int [PK]
ParentId   int [FK]
FirstName  nvarchar(100)
LastName   nvarchar(100)
CreateUser int
CreateDate datetime
UpdateUser int
UpdateDate datetime
```

You will have 2 options to assigning a parent

```
person1.Tbl_Persons = person2;
```

where person1 and person2 are both `TblPersons` objects, or simply assign the Id

```
person1.ParentId = person2.PersonId;
```

---

Now, a **complete code** as what I normally do to **insert/update in the database**

```
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    MyEntities db = new MyEntities();
    DateTime now = DateTime.UTCNow;

    public void Save() {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    #region Update / Insert Persons

    public void UpdatePerson(Tbl_Persons person, int parentId, int userId)
    {
        // let's check if record is in db
        Tbl_Persons p = this.GetPersonById(person.PersonId); 
        if(p == null)
            p = new Person(); // person was not found in db

        p.FirstName = person.FirstName;
        p.LastName = person.LastName;

        // we can now hook up the parent object in 2 ways
        // or set the Id, or attach the hole object
        // NOTE: only choose one line!
        p.MyParent = parentId;
        p.TblParent = this.GetPersonById(parentId);

        // update info
        p.UpdateDate = now;
        p.UpdateUser = userId;


        if(p.PersonId == 0)
        {
            // is it new person in db, so we need to INSERT into the db
            p.CreateDate = now;
            p.CreateUser = userId;

            db.Tbl_Persons.AddObject(p);
        }
        else
        {
            // It's an existing person, we do need need to do anything
            // as internally once we assign a new value to the object that
            // come back from the database, EF sets Modified flag on this
        }

        // let's save
        this.Save();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Queries

        public Tbl_Persons GetPersonById(int personId)
        { 
            return db.Tbl_Persons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PersonId == personId);
        }

    #endregion

}
```

in your **Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Tbl_Persons model, int parentId)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.UpdatePerson(model, parentId, currentUserId);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

hope it helps.